# Usage of object destructuring in Array.reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

I was trying to solve another person's problem on SO using `Array.prototype.reduce` and `...object` destructuring. I don't understand why it works as expected when I'm using `Object.assign`, but not when using the spread operator.

```js
const str = 'Jack:13,Phil:15,Lucy:12'

const arr = str.split(',')

let reducer = (acc, val) => {
  return { ...acc,
    ...{
      [val.split(':')[0]]: Number(val.split(':')[1])
    }
  }
}

let reducer2 = (acc, val) => {
  return Object.assign(acc, {
    [val.split(':')[0]]: Number(val.split(':')[1])
  })
}

let obj = {
  Jody: 29
}

let obj2 = {
  Julie: 28
}

arr.reduce(reducer, obj)
arr.reduce(reducer2, obj2)

console.log(obj)
/* output:
{
  "Jody": 29
}
*/
console.log(obj2)
/* output:
{
  "Julie": 28,
  "Jack": 13,
  "Phil": 15,
  "Lucy": 12
}
*/
```

Comment: `Object.assign(acc`  Does not create a new array,..  `...acc` creates a new array.

Comment: Using `...{…}` makes no sense. Just put the properties directly in the object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array `reduce` is often used to return a new value. Even if it mutates an accumulator, it's safe to assume that it can return a new value.

`arr.reduce(reducer, obj)` relies on that `obj` is mutated. `reducer2` mutates original object indeed, this is the reason why it works. But this contradicts with `reducer` which keeps an accumulator immutable.

It should be:

```
obj = arr.reduce(reducer, obj);
```

Comment: I used to think that whatever is returned by `reducer` in every loop-step becomes the new `acc`.

Comment: @connexo  It does, but obj is still pointing at the original,..  And is why Object.assign worked, as it was still working on the original..

Comment: So `obj` is not passed by reference when doing `arr.reduce(reducer, obj)`?

Comment: @connexo It's able to return new acc, but you're returning same object on each iteration in reducer2 and new object in reducer. `Object.assign(obj) === obj`, `{...obj} !== obj` (which is syntactic sugar for `Object.assign({}, obj)` ).

Comment: `So obj is not passed by reference`  It is, but your replacing it when you do.  `{...acc}`, and because you then never use the return of reduce, the original object is left untouched.

Comment: Since I passed `obj` as the initial value, which becomes `acc` inside the reducer function, I was expecting `obj` to automatically become whatever the reducer function returns in each iteration.

Comment: Immutability as stated in the answer is a concept I only heard about and am not familiar with. Can you elaborate more on that in your answer? tbh I still don't understand it.

Comment: @connexo It isn't possible in JS to assign new value to a variable without directly assigning it to a variable like `obj = ...`. Regarding immutability, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object . This allows to detect changes in the object by checking its reference. If `oldObjReference === newObjReference` you can be sure that it wasn't changed, and if `oldObjReference !== newObjReference` you can be sure that it was *potentially* changed. This principle is widely used for change detection in frameworks, namely React.